# Solving a differential equation with a stochastic force term with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I am asking how `NDSolve` can be used to solve the following differential equation,

What is the correct code to solve the following differential equation nummerically (oscillating particle with mass `m`, friction coefficient `k`, random white noise force `randomForce`)?

```
m*x''[t] + k*x'[t] - randomForce[t] == 0
```

with `x[0] == 0; x'[0] == 0;`

Here is my code which lacks the appropriate options an parameters, causing `NDSolve` to produce an error at the end.

```
m = 6.137*10^-10; (* in g *)

k = 9.2055*10^-10; (* in g/s *)

temperature = 600; (* in K *)

kB = 1.3806488*10^-16 (* in erg/K *)

stddev = Sqrt[2*k*temperature*kB] 

1.23497*10^-11

whiteNoise = WhiteNoiseProcess[stddev];

randomForce[t_Real] := RandomVariate[whiteNoise[t]];

tmax = 50;

s = NDSolve[
   {m*x''[t] + k*x'[t] - randomForce[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}
   , x, {t, 0, tmax}
   ];
```

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 610327 steps reached at the point t == 0.11124384151728325`.

Comment: I don't know much about integrating random processes, but you might be interested in [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html). It seems `NDSolve` keeps the steps very small because the randomness makes the error estimate large. You could try options like `Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-3`, but you're probably better off with one of the stochastic solvers. (Well, that's my naive advice.)

Comment: Maybe you could clarify further what you're seeking.  `NDSolve` does not have solvers to integrate SDEs.  "It's the wrong tool. Try something else." -- that's the answer to this Q. The suggestion in my comment seems to be the [Euler–Maruyama method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maruyama_method), but you didn't reply.  The alternative seems to be to use the answer in the linked Q&A.  If that answer is an unsatisfactory solution of this SDE, please explain.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the documentation for Stochastic Differential Equation Processes: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html

Comment: @Michael E2, Sjoerd Smit: Thank you for your helpfull comments. especially about: "NDSolve does not have solvers to integrate SDEs. "It's the wrong tool.". So I will read the content at your links thoroughly.