# How to reformulate differential equation problem as OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have the following differential equation

```
m*x''[t] + k*x'[t] - randomForce[t] == 0
```

which describes an oscillating particle with mass `m`, moving in a medium with friction coefficient `k` and excited by a random white noise force `randomForce`.

As I understand from the documentation (guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses) instead of solving the differential equation I could also use e.g. the corresponding `OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess`.

In my case are: `m = 6.137*10^-10; (* in g *); k = 9.2055*10^-10; (* in g/s *)`.

**How can the `OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess` be used to solve the upper differential equation?**

Please see also the related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170805/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could do:

```
k = 9.2055*10^-10;
m = 6.137*10^-10;

proc[x0_, v0_, γ_, f_] = ItoProcess[
     {\[DifferentialD]x[t] == v[t] \[DifferentialD]t, 
      \[DifferentialD]v[t] == -γ v[t] \[DifferentialD]t + f \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, 
     {x[t], v[t]}, {{x, v}, {x0, v0}}, t,  w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

Then one can calculate properties:

```
Mean[proc[x0, v0, γ, f][t]]
(* {(v0 - E^(-t γ) v0 + x0 γ)/γ, E^(-t γ) v0} *)
```

or do simulations:

```
sims0 = RandomFunction[proc[0.5, 1.1,  k/m, 0.0], {0., 10., 0.01}]
sims = RandomFunction[proc[0.5, 1.1,  k/m, 0.2], {0., 10., 0.01}]

ListLinePlot[{sims0["ValueList"][[1, All, 1]], sims["ValueList"][[1, All, 1]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f=0.0", "f=0.2"}, {Right, Center}], AxesLabel -> {"time", "x[t]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help ... I do not understand why x is saturating, that should not be the case for the given differential equation (there is no confining potential).

Comment: See if you agree with `Simplify[Limit[Mean[proc[x0, v0, \[Gamma], f][t]], t -> Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> {\[Gamma] > 0, (x0 | v0) \[Element] Reals}]`.

Comment: Yes correct, I agree. When I use the parameters drift and volatility in `WienerProcess` then it looks to me more “real”, like what I see in experiments. I have to play around with these two parameters.

Comment: How would you extend this solution to obtain the movement in 2d? Is this correct: `sims=RandomFunction[proc[0.5, 1.1, k/m, 1], {0.1, 10., 0.1}, 2]`and then `ListLinePlot[sims[[2, 1, 1]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: You would need to define the 2d equations of motion along the same lines (and decide whether the forces are correlated, ...).